# Prolog Flow Free solver

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, prolog-toplevel

I'm completely new to Prolog and working on a homework assignment My program is supposed to solve flow free problem using depth first, I don't need the whole code for it as its what supposed to do but I need to know how to think to solve it or what parts it will contain.

[image]

the points look like that:

```
dot('R',[3,1],[0,3]).
```

so this 2 points is red and suppose to connect them

so I was thinking that there will be moves to move from 1 point to another and already it works

```
move([R,C],[NR,NC]):-

    move_right(R,C,NR,NC).

move([R,C],[NR,NC]):-
     move_Left(R,C,NR,NC).

move([R,C],[NR,NC]):-

    move_Up(R,C,NR,NC).

move([R,C],[NR,NC]):-

    move_Down(R,C,NR,NC).
```

I think now I need to think about the start and the goal so the start is initial grid which contain points with there colors and they all are not connected so I need to take element from start for example red point and find all paths between the 2 points by using moves then for each element I will have multiple paths so what should I do and is there a goal which I will stop for it ?


May be the question is confusing but really don't know how to solve it specially when trying to
get useful from backtracking.


All I need to know that I need for example a function to take something and return another something and so on, without its implementation and I will do that

Comment: The puzzle is also known as "numberlink". If you can solve this fast, I guess you get hired by a Very large-scale integration (VLSI) company. This is like pin wiring.

Answer (score 1):

This is some extensive problem.

Here are some quick hints:

Represent a state of the search space as 5x5 tiles, each of which is non-colored or colored in one of the 5 available colours. With SWI-Prolog, you have the fantastic [*dict*](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=bidicts) datastructure (an associative array), so we can put this to good use instead of messing around with low-level index computations (might be a bit slower, but who cares!)

Our convention is *row number first, column number second*

```
  +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
  | 0,0 | 0,1 | 0,2 | 0,3 | 0,4 |
  +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
  | 1,0 | 1,1 | 1,2 | 1,3 | 1,4 |
  +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
  | 2,0 | 2,1 | 2,2 | 2,3 | 2,4 |
  +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
  | 3,0 | 3,1 | 3,2 | 3,3 | 3,4 |
  +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
  | 4,0 | 4,1 | 4,2 | 4,3 | 4,4 |
  +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Our clean board is then represented as:

```
Board =
 _{ 0 : _{ 0 : black, 1: black, 2: black, 3: black, 4: black },
    1 : _{ 0 : black, 1: black, 2: black, 3: black, 4: black },
    2 : _{ 0 : black  1: black, 2: black, 3: black, 4: black },
    3 : _{ 0 : black, 1: black, 2: black, 3: black, 4: black },
    4 : _{ 0 : black, 1: black, 2: black, 3: black, 4: black } }.
```

We also have 5 pens, starting off a one or the end extremity of a *path*.
The pens have the status `fesh` (they haven't even put to the board), `done` (a valid path has been traced and the pen won't nove) or `ready`.

```
Pens = 
_{ blue   : { row: 0, col: 0, status: fresh },
   red    : { row: 0, col: 3, status: fresh },  
   yellow : { row: 1, col: 3, status: fresh }, 
   orange : { row: 0, col: 4, status: fresh }, 
   green  : { row: 3, col: 4, status: fresh } }.
```

A state of the search space is thus given by:

```
State = [ Board, Pens ].
```

And now the depth-first search

A predicate `move(Board,Pens)` is given the `State` and deterministically:

- Selects a pen that is not `done` yet (the colors are selected in fixed, but otherwise freely selectable order; a fun way to do that would be to generate a random sequence of the colors determinsitically from the board state).
- Selects a move for that pen that is possible (again, such that on "redo" a next possible move. If no move is possible, fails, causing backtracking.

  - Special case: if the pen is `fresh`, the only possible move is to color the tile under the pen and set the pen to `ready`.
- Generates a new board *dict* from the existing one.
- Checks whether the path for the pen has been completed. In that case, the pen's color is set to `done`.
- Checks whether all the paths have been completed.

  - In that case, succeeds.
  - Otherwise, calls itself with the new `Board` and `Pens`.

Comment: I didn't understand the whole answer 
1- where is next point as Pens contain only one row and one col should I add it?
2- what happen if I move by order in pens (not use random colors)
3- I will change move predicate to take  Pens and the Board and then take one pen and try to make a move(up, down, left, right) and return new Board after changing color(if its fresh)other wise the board still same and the Pens will be the same if not reaching end point  ?

Comment: 1)- Given a "State" you would freely decide what the next point should be (according to a deterministic procedure). There would be no point in storing it. You would have a predicate `move_single_pen(Board,Pens,Color,NewBoard,NewPens)` which builds the `NewBoard` and `NewPens` from the current `Board`, `Pens` and a fixed `Color`. On backtracking, it would generate all the possible moves for the pen with color `Color`. 2) That would work too. 3) if there is no valid move, the predicate should fail, changing nothing.

Comment: @MostowskiCollapse It's not well written. I want to express that one needs to generate several solutions (Prolog non-determinism) but in a repeatable way with a fixed sequence (deterministically).

Comment: It possibly slows down the search, this additional freedom of "Selects a pen" in your sketch. Like if you have 2 pens A and B. And lets say you search 4 steps. Then you search AABB, ABAB, BAAB, BABA and BBAA. But they are all equivalent sequences concerning the board effect. (A normal form in an Abelian Group would be A^2*B^2, you only need to search these normal forms).

Comment: Nevertheless the idea could have some benefit. The normal form need not be A^n*B^m, could be also something else. Some strategy to interleave pen choices, as long as you dont backtrack over different strategies. SAT solvers do such things during labeling.

Answer (score 1):

Just imagine you have to switch trains, and your time table will tell you to change tracks. For the time table search algorithm, switching trains is just a possible move. We do the same, in our search concerning pens 1,2,3,4 and 5:

```
  +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
  |  1  |     |     |  2  |  4  |
  +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
  |     |     |     |  3  |     |
  +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
  |     |     |  3  |     |     |
  +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
  |     |  2  |  4  |     |  5  |
  +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
  |     |  1  |  5  |     |     |
  +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

(instead of colors just numbers, the puzzle is then called [numberlink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numberlink))

First there is the search for a single pen, which is the classical path/4 predicate:

```
path(X, X, L, L) :- !.
path(X, Z, L, R) :-
   next(X, Y),
   \+ member(Y, L),
   path(Y, Z, [Y|L], R).
```

We can use the already visited list L, to comfort a multi-pen search:

```
multi([], L, L).
multi([X-Y|M], L, R) :-
   \+ member(X, L),
   path(X, Y, [X|L], H),
   multi(M, H, R).
```

Seems to work, since the example board is rather small:

```
?- multi([(0,4)-(1,0),(1,1)-(3,4),(2,2)-(3,3),
       (2,1)-(4,4),(2,0)-(4,1)],[],L), write(L), nl.
[(4,1),(4,0),(3,0),(2,0),(4,4),(4,3),(4,2),(3,2),
(3,1),(2,1),(3,3),(2,3),(2,2),(3,4),(2,4),(1,4),
(1,3),(1,2),(1,1),(1,0),(0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(0,3),(0,4)]
```

Open Source:

**Brute Force Numberlink Solver**
https://gist.github.com/jburse/8c387824f82c239cbf02f3ba893bcf02#file-path-pl

Comment: I have never heard of dogelog :-)

Comment: Dogelog runtime now supports (?-)/1.